# What''s the optimal method to extract a list of users and their information from Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory

I have a need to sync Active Directory information with another system.  I need to pull out a list of AD users, and all their info (first name, last name, email -- anything stored with their record in AD, essentially.)

I did this once before -- years ago -- and it involved running a command line utility to export the AD user database to an XML file, which I then parsed.

Is this still the right way to do it, or have things changed in the intervening years?  Any chance the domain controller has some sort of real-time Web service now?

Comment: What OS are you using? 2003 or 2008?

Comment: 2003 or 2008? Have you looked at dsget.exe, dsquery.exe or csvde.exe yet?

Comment: I'd also be curious what you plan to do with the data. That might change someone's potential answer as to the best tool for the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PowerShell in the way to go.  The Get-Aduser  (or the Quest equiv - get-Qaduser) command will easily get the user information and powershell will export to csv, xml, etc.

Your next best option are the DS* utilities (dsget, dssearch, etc) will find user info as well.  They work well, but Powershell is the wave of the future and you'll find a lot of help for it these days.